# Cast the current object ($this) to a descendent class

Tags: php, oop, type-conversion, downcast

I have a class where it may be necessary to change the object to a descendent class further down the line. Is this possible? I know that one option is to return a copy of it but using the child class instead, but it'd be nice to actually modify the current object... so:

```
class myClass {
  protected $var;

  function myMethod()
  {
    // function which changes the class of this object
    recast(myChildClass); 
  }
}

class myChildClass extends myClass {
}

$obj = new myClass();
$obj->myMethod();
get_class_name($obj); // => myChildClass
```

Comment: I have a function that will do this, but it's not something that you should normally do (impossible code for anybody else to understand). What's wrong with implementing a standard factory method?

Comment: @Mark Baker: Could you post your code?  I'd be curious how you do it without using something like runkit...

Comment: Please tell us why you want to do this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can, as described in other answers, do it with nasty *black magic* PECL extensions.

Though, you seriously don't want it. Any problem you want to solve in OOP there's an OOP-compliant way to do it.

Runtime type hierarchy modifications are not OOP-compliant (in fact, this is consciously avoided). There are design patterns that should fit what you want.

Please, tell us why do you want that, I'm sure there must be better ways to do it ;)

Comment: Thanks. The method I'm going with is to simulate it by making the parent class a mapper for the child classes. It sounds messy, but I'm pretty sure I can make it clean. I've got the idea in my head of what it should look like, and I'm just working on getting it onto the computer screen.

Comment: This is the first time I hear polymorphism is avoided and not OOP-complient. I thought it was contrary, one the basic principles. Is that soem different polymorphism called "type polymorphism".

Comment: I meant here "type swapping" or whatever you'd better want to call it. Polymorphism the OOP way is availability for using specialized subtypes in place of supertypes, which is neat; but not the other way around.

Comment: The only type-safe way I know for some sort of this happening (which can be very useful in some contexts) (is not on PHP) is called self-types in Scala. And it works because you can provide type information prior to the actual execution, so it's type-safe, but that probably falls a bit out of OOP already.

Comment: I disagree. Polymorphism is one of the key principles of OOP. Of course, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: I think it's more of a design choice. Polymorphism is overwhelmingly popular with very good reason. (Flexibility while maintaining code integrity) However, CASTING of any kind has it's benefits and drawbacks. As one commenter stated, "great power comes with great responsibility". I believe that PHP should allow for downcasting.

Comment: PHP already allows you to use the object as the descendant class (aka "downcast") *if* the original object *is* of the descendant class (you can use instanceof to check), but **swapping the class of an object at runtime is definitely not OOP**. If you want to wrap an object onto something that could be a subclass, you could use the Decorator Pattern and have the Decorator be a subclass of your parent object.

Answer (score 41):

Casting to change the object's type is not possible in PHP (without using a nasty extension).  Once you instantiate a object, you can't change the class (or other implementation details) anymore...

You can simulate it with a method like so:

```
public function castAs($newClass) {
    $obj = new $newClass;
    foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $name) {
        $obj->$key = $name;
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->foo = 'bar';
$newObj = $obj->castAs('myChildClass');
echo $newObj->foo; // bar
```

But beware that it doesn't actually change the original class.  It just creates a new one.  And beware that this requires that the properties are public or have getter and setter magic methods...

And if you wanted some more checks (I'd suggest so), I'd add this line as the first line of `castAs` to prevent issues:

```
if (!$newClass instanceof self) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        'Can\'t change class hierarchy, you must cast to a child class'
    );
}
```

---

Alright, since Gordon posted a very black-magic solution, I will do the same (using the [RunKit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit.php) PECL extension (warning: *here be dragons*):

```
class myClass {}
class myChildClass extends MyClass {}

function getInstance($classname) {
    //create random classname
    $tmpclass = 'inheritableClass'.rand(0,9);
    while (class_exists($tmpclass))
        $tmpclass .= rand(0,9);
    $code = 'class '.$tmpclass.' extends '.$classname.' {}';
    eval($code);
    return new $tmpclass();
}

function castAs($obj, $class) {
    $classname = get_class($obj);
    if (stripos($classname, 'inheritableClass') !== 0)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Class is not castable'
        );
    runkit_class_emancipate($classname);
    runkit_class_adopt($classname, $class);
}
```

So, instead of doing `new Foo`, you'd do something like this:

```
$obj = getInstance('MyClass');
echo $obj instanceof MyChildClass; //false
castAs($obj, 'myChildClass');
echo $obj instanceof MyChildClass; //true
```

And from within the class (as long as it was created with `getInstance`):

```
echo $this instanceof MyChildClass; //false
castAs($this, 'myChildClass');
echo $this instanceof MyChildClass; //true
```

**Disclaimer: Don't do this.  Really, don't.  It's possible, but it's such a horrible idea...**

Comment: This trick is good way to make ugly code. I would rather stayed with what language gives and try to "favour composition over inheritance"...

Comment: PHP 5.5+ stay with "NO CAST" problem at 2013s?

Answer (score 12):

**Redefining Classes**

You can do this with the [runkit PECL extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) aka the "Toolkit from Hell":

- [`runkit_class_adopt`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-class-adopt.php) — Convert a base class to an inherited class, add ancestral methods when appropriate
- [`runkit_class_emancipate`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-class-emancipate.php) — Convert an inherited class to a base class, removes any method whose scope is ancestral

---

**Redefining Instances**

The runkit functions do not work on object instances. If you want to do that on object instances, you could theoretically do that by messing with the serialized object strings.
This is the realms of **black magic** though.

The code below allows you to change an instance to whatever other class:

```
function castToObject($instance, $className)
{
    if (!is_object($instance)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Argument 1 must be an Object'
        );
    }
    if (!class_exists($className)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Argument 2 must be an existing Class'
        );
    }
    return unserialize(
        sprintf(
            'O:%d:"%s"%s',
            strlen($className),
            $className,
            strstr(strstr(serialize($instance), '"'), ':')
        )
    );
}
```

---

**Example:**

```
class Foo
{
    private $prop1;
    public function __construct($arg)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $arg;
    }
    public function getProp1()
    {
        return $this->prop1;
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected $prop2;
    public function getProp2()
    {
        return $this->prop2;
    }
}
$foo = new Foo('test');
$bar = castToObject($foo, 'Bar');
var_dump($bar);
```

**Result:**

```
object(Bar)#3 (2) {
  ["prop2":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["prop1":"Foo":private]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

As you can see, the resulting object is a `Bar` object now with all properties retaining their visibility but `prop2` is `NULL`. The ctor doesnt allow this, so technically, while you have a `Bar` child of `Foo`, it is not in a valid state. You could add a magic `__wakeup` method to handle this somehow, but seriously, you dont want that and it shows why casting is ugly business.

***DISCLAIMER: I absolutely do not encourage anyone to use any of these solutions in production.***

Comment: @ircmaxell none for Toolkit of Hell? :)

Comment: Well, I thought that was being a bit sympathetic (considering how nasty it is)...

Comment: @Mark thanks. Btw, you might want to flag your question to mods and ask if they can permadelete it. I already flagged it but mods might be more inclined to do so when author ask for it. Not sure if they can do that at all though.

Comment: @Gordon - duly flagged... it wasn't ever code meant to see the light of day anyway - and I'd be happier knowing that nobody with enough points to see deleted answers can ever pick up on it and start using it in a real application. I certainly won't publish my disinherit() reversal function (change child object to its parent).

Comment: y'know, you give a disclaimer but not much justification with it ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because while an instance of a child class is also an instance of a parent class, the reverse is not true.

What you could do is create a new instance of the child class and copy the values from the old object onto it.  You can then return the new object which will be of type `myChildClass`.

Answer (score 1):

For simple classes this may work (I am using this successfully in some rare cases):

```
function castAs($sourceObject, $newClass)
{
    $castedObject                    = new $newClass();
    $reflectedSourceObject           = new \ReflectionClass($sourceObject);
    $reflectedSourceObjectProperties = $reflectedSourceObject->getProperties();

    foreach ($reflectedSourceObjectProperties as $reflectedSourceObjectProperty) {
        $propertyName = $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->getName();

        $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->setAccessible(true);

        $castedObject->$propertyName = $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->getValue($sourceObject);
    }
}
```

Usage in my case:

```
$indentFormMapper = castAs($formMapper, IndentedFormMapper::class);
```

More abstract:

```
$castedObject = castAs($sourceObject, TargetClass::class);
```

Of course `TargetClass` has to inherit from the class of `sourceObject` and you have to make all protected and private properties public in `TargetClass` to get this work.

I use this to change `FormMapper` (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Form/FormMapper.php) on the fly to `IndentedFormMapper` by adding a new method called `chain`:

```
class IndentedFormMapper extends FormMapper
{
    /**
     * @var AdminInterface
     */
    public $admin;

    /**
     * @var BuilderInterface
     */
    public $builder;

    /**
     * @var FormBuilderInterface
     */
    public $formBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentGroup;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentTab;

    /**
     * @var bool|null
     */
    public $apply;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function chain($callback)
    {
        $callback($this);

        return $this;
    }
}
```