# Custom code format for specified code in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, sonata-admin, jetbrains-ide, formatter

The PHP code for Sonata Admin using "with" is formatted by the auto formatter like this:

```
$formMapper->with('User')
           ->add('firstName')
           ->add('lastName')
           ->end()
           ->with('Additional Information')
           ->add('gender')
           ->end()
```

To get a more human readable code style I currently disable and enable the formatter and format the code like this:

```
// @formatter:off
$formMapper
    ->with('User')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
    ->end()
    ->with('Additional Information')
        ->add('gender')
    ->end()
;
// @formatter:on
```

Is there a way to define a code style for a specific code phrase? E.g with regex to format the code automatically to the second style?

Comment: You must write a custom plugin, unfortunately Intellij doesn't provide this feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution especially for the case in sonata admin by extending the php code to make it "autoformattable". Here is what I have done:

`ObjectTypeCaster.php` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081037/301277):

```
class ObjectTypeCaster
{
    /**
     * This method is able to recast an object by copying all properties
     */
    public static function castAs($sourceObject, $newClass)
    {
        $castedObject                    = new $newClass();
        $reflectedSourceObject           = new \ReflectionClass($sourceObject);
        $reflectedSourceObjectProperties = $reflectedSourceObject->getProperties();

        foreach ($reflectedSourceObjectProperties as $reflectedSourceObjectProperty) {
            $propertyName = $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->getName();

            $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->setAccessible(true);

            $castedObject->$propertyName = $reflectedSourceObjectProperty->getValue($sourceObject);
        }

        return $castedObject;
    }
}
```

Extend the `FormMapper` and `ShowMapper` like this:

`IndentedFormMapper.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Form;

use App\Helper\ObjectTypeCaster;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\BuilderInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\FormContractorInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class IndentedFormMapper extends FormMapper
{
    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseMapper public
     *
     * @var AdminInterface
     */
    public $admin;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseMapper public
     *
     * @var BuilderInterface
     */
    public $builder;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from FormMapper public
     *
     * @var FormBuilderInterface
     */
    public $formBuilder;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentGroup;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentTab;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var bool|null
     */
    public $apply;

    /**
     * We overwrite the constructor from FormMapper and BaseMapper to be able to create
     * this object without any parameter. Its properties are copied by ObjectTypeCaster.
     *
     * IndentedFormMapper constructor.
     *
     * @see ObjectTypeCaster
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * This makes it possible to chain this object in a way that allows
     * autoformatting in IntelliJ IDEs. Usage:
     *
     * $formMapper
     *     ->tab('General')
     *     ->chain(function ($formMapper) {
     *         $formMapper
     *             ->add('...')
     *             // Default usage here, you can also chain again
     *         ;
     *     })
     *     ->end()
     * ;
     *
     * @param $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function chain($callback)
    {
        $callback($this);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

`IndentedShowMapper.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Form;

use App\Helper\ObjectTypeCaster;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\BuilderInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Builder\FormContractorInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class IndentedShowMapper extends ShowMapper
{
    /**
     * Makes protected property from ShowMapper public
     *
     * @var AdminInterface
     */
    public $list;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentGroup;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $currentTab;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseGroupedMapper public
     *
     * @var bool|null
     */
    public $apply;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseMapper public
     *
     * @var AdminInterface
     */
    public $admin;

    /**
     * Makes protected property from BaseMapper public
     *
     * @var BuilderInterface
     */
    public $builder;

    /**
     * We overwrite the constructor from ShowMapper and BaseMapper to be able to create
     * this object without any parameter. Its properties are copied by ObjectTypeCaster.
     *
     * IndentedFormMapper constructor.
     *
     * @see ObjectTypeCaster
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * This makes it possible to chain this object in a way that allows
     * autoformatting in IntelliJ IDEs. Usage:
     *
     * $showMapper
     *     ->tab('General')
     *     ->chain(function ($showMapper) {
     *         $showMapper
     *             ->add('...')
     *             // Default usage here, you can also chain again
     *         ;
     *     })
     *     ->end()
     * ;
     *
     * @param $callback
     * @return $this
     */
    public function chain($callback)
    {
        $callback($this);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Add a `BaseAdmin` class from that you inherit in all your admin classes and add the following methods:

```
<?php

use App\Admin\Form\IndentedFormMapper;
use App\Admin\Form\IndentedShowMapper;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Helper\ObjectTypeCaster;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Mapper\BaseMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class BaseAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $indentFormMapper = ObjectTypeCaster::castAs($formMapper, IndentedFormMapper::class);

        $this->configureFormFieldsIndention($indentFormMapper);
    }

    /**
     * @param IndentedFormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFieldsIndention(IndentedFormMapper $formMapper)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $indentShowMapper = ObjectTypeCaster::castAs($showMapper, IndentedShowMapper::class);

        $this->configureShowFieldsIndention($indentShowMapper);
    }

    /**
     * @param IndentedShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFieldsIndention(IndentedShowMapper $showMapper)
    {

    }
}
```

Use it in your `BaseAdmin` child classes like this:

`ExampleAdmin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use App\Admin\Form\IndentedFormMapper;
use App\Admin\Form\IndentedShowMapper;
use App\Entity\Example;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class ExampleAdmin extends BaseAdmin
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param IndentedFormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFieldsIndention(IndentedFormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->tab('General')
            ->chain(function ($formMapper) {
                $formMapper
                    ->with(
                        'Example',
                        [
                            'class' => AdminLayout::HALF,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->chain(function ($formMapper) {
                        $formMapper
                            ->add(
                                'name',
                                Types::TEXT
                            )
                        ;
                    })
                    ->end()
                ;
            })
            ->end()
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param IndentedShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFieldsIndention(IndentedShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $mapData = $this->getMapData();

        $showMapper
            ->with('Internal')
            ->chain(function ($showMapper) {
                $showMapper
                    ->add('id')
                    ->add('createdAt')
                    ->add('updatedAt')
                ;
            })
            ->end()
        ;
    }
}
```